# Evaluate outer function first

Tags: evaluation, functional-style

I'm new in Mathematica so this is maybe super easy to do, but I can't figure out how.

I've got a function `plus[a,b]` that sums two numbers and I need to implement a function `derivation[a]` that will derive the input like this:

```
derivation[e_Integer] (* returns 0 *)
derivation[x] (* returns 1 *)
```

I've got a problem with this rule:

```
derivation[plus[a, b]] := plus[derivation[a], derivation[b]];
```

When I implement it this way, it doesn't work because plus is evaluated before derivation. I.E. `derivation[plus[x, 3]]` should return `1`. Is there some other way how to implement it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built-in `D` or `Derivative`? You might want to look at giving your `derivation` a `HoldAll` attribute.

Comment: Awesome, that's the attribute I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Yes I know about built-in `Derivative`, but I need to implement it on my own for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to not leave this unanswered, as rm -rf suggested in comment, setting the attribute `HoldAll` to `derivation` function solved my problem.